# Error expected identifier before token "<"

Tags: c++, c++11, syntax-error, structure, shared-data

I am a beginner in C++. I have this header file called SharedData.h. Its given below.

```
//SharedData.h

#include <memory>

typedef struct Shared_data
{
    std::string _data;
    bool IsConsumedbyNodeA;
    bool IsConsumedbyNodeB;

public:
    Shared_data():
        tokenizer_data(""),IsConsumedbyNodeA(false),IsConsumedbyNodeB(false){};
    Shared_data& ReadSharedData();
    void WriteSharedData(Shared_data &);
}Shared_data;

extern std::shared_ptr<Shared_data> ptr_to_Shared_data;//I am getting the above mentioned error here
```

The shared_ptr is being defined in Shared_data.cpp so that I get single copy of the object in memory and extern declaration wherever I include the header.

I tried a lot but don't know how to resolve this error.

Please Help.....

Regards,
TechTotie

Comment: The compiler doesn't know what a `std::shared_ptr` is, try `#include <memory>` in the `.h` file.

Comment: I have already included header file #include<memory> Just forgot to mention it here.Sorry for that.

Comment: did you enable building with C++11?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am using mingw32 for compilation. I think it does support C++ 11.

Comment: In most cases you have to manually enable building with C++11 (even if compiler does support it). Check your compilation flags.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the header `memory`.

Comment: I have already included header file #include<memory> Just forgot to mention it here.Sorry for that.

Comment: @TechTotie Have you told your compiler to use C++11 mode? For `clang` and `gcc` you need to add the flag `-std=c++11`. Failing this, have you checked your compiler actually supports C++11? `gcc --version` should be at least 4.8 and `clang --version` at least 3.4.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am using mingw32 for compilation. I think it does support C++ 11. But still I will give a try using -std=c++11 flag and I will also check the gcc version.

Comment: I checked the version in MingW with "gcc --version" it is "gcc.exe (GCC) 4.8.1". Does it support C++11? and I tried with -std=c++11 but it did not work.It's giving "cc1plus.exe: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=c++11"".

Comment: @TechTotie Yes, it should. You shouldn't pass those commands directly to `cc1plus` but to `g++`. Unfortunately I'm not familiar with MinGW and can't help you with this.

Answer (score 0):

For use `std::shared_ptr` you should enable support for C++11 standard and include header `memory`.

Comment: I have already included header file #include<memory> Just forgot to mention it here.Sorry for that.